# Put two images on table in the opposite corners

Tags: java, libgdx, gui

I want to put my two images on the opposite corners of my table: one on bottom left, the second on the bottom right. How to achieve that?

I have tried `align()` and `left()`/`right()`. None of these worked. Now they stick to each other on the bottom center.

```java
public class BottomControlls {
    
    private Stage stage;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private Image imageLeftDrawerControll;
    private Image imageRightDrawerControll;
    
    public BottomControlls(SpriteBatch sb, Camera camera) {
        viewport = new FitViewport(7 * 32, 12 * 32, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);
    
        Table table = new Table();
        table.setSize(camera.viewportWidth, 32);
    
        Pixmap bgPixmap = new Pixmap(1,1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        bgPixmap.setColor(Color.valueOf("00000080"));
        bgPixmap.fill();
        TextureRegionDrawable textureRegionDrawableBg = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(bgPixmap)));
        table.setBackground(textureRegionDrawableBg);
    
        table.bottom();
    
    
        table.setDebug(true);
    
    
        imageLeftDrawerControll = new Image(new Texture("arrow_right.png"));
        imageRightDrawerControll = new Image(new Texture("arrow_left.png"));
    
        table.add(imageLeftDrawerControll).size(45, 32).align(Align.left);
        table.add(imageRightDrawerControll).size(45, 32).align(Align.right);
        
    
        stage.addActor(table);
    }
}
```